# Need to connect two instances of an application together C#

Tags: c#

Problem:

I have an instance of an application on one computer (C# VS 2015), it is connected to a database (SQL).

I have other instances of the same application on other computers.

All computers are connected, and all instances are working with the same database.

When the software writes into the database, the UI will change accordingly.

Question:

How to I refresh the UI of EVERY instance when any machine changes the database?

Example:

Clicking buttonA:
1. Create record in database.
2. Change buttonA background color to green.
3. Tell other computers to refresh their instances to show their buttonA as green too.

Hope this wasn't a stupid question, I appreciate all help!

Comment: Which RDBMS you are using?

Comment: Please read [ask] and share your research, before people go and suggest the first Google hit for "C# detect database change" without explaining all possible drawbacks.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a stupid question, but rather a very common requirement. The best solution (in my opinion) would be to create a WCF service all clients talk to.

Only the service performs operations on the database and is designed as a two-way service. That way, once a client is connected, the service can instruct it to refresh itself if another client changed something. No client would change the database itself.

If that isn't possible, I'm afraid polling the database for changes is the only common option that works for any RDBMS. There may be other options for the RDBMS you're using.

Comment: It's not the only solution and there exist other solution like hook into DB and let DB notify for each change. I am talking about `message broker architecture`

Comment: True, that is what I said. Depending on the RDBMS there may be other solutions, but polling works for any storage system.

Answer (score 0):

How fast do you need to refresh? If you have some seconds, then I would suggest to use a polling approach: just query the database every x seconds, for all records updated *after* the previous poll.

The returned records are those to be refreshed in the UI. Indexing that datetime field would help to minimize the impact of frequent/multiple queries.

Comment: That would be huge waste of resources. Have you considered that?

Comment: @Rahul, as mentioned, it depends on the frequency. Polling is a usual and valid technique for some specific use cases. Other push-to-client solutions are valid as well, with a longer learning curve and an adequate backend support.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a web based UI then something like [SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr) would do this for you. I've used this before and it works great.

Comment: SignalR helps with pushing updates from a web application to its front-end. It doesn't help with the actual question here, detecting database changes, which is required because all clients write to the database directly.